# pydantic UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2

Tags: pymongo, pydantic-v2

I'm getting an error related to migrating the Pydantic version. Code made in v1, and pydantic installed in v2.

[image]

[image]

I try replace the class Config for the model_config, but i don't had success and the error continued the same. I tried too replace the field for de annotation, but i dont have success.

the codes where i do using pydantic:

config:

```
from pydantic import BaseConfig


class Settings(BaseConfig):
    DATABASE_URL: str
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: str

    ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN: int
    REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN: int
    JWT_ALGORITHM: str

    CLIENT_ORIGIN: str

    JWT_PRIVATE_KEY: str
    JWT_PUBLIC_KEY: str

    class Config:
        env_file = "./env"


settings = Settings()
```

model (here i dont know how i could add the prop json_encoders in model config):

```
from typing import List, Annotated

from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, BaseConfig, ConfigDict


class OID(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        try:
            return ObjectId(str(v))
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("not a valid ObjectId")


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((type(self),) + tuple(self.__dict__.values()))


class Projects(MyBaseModel):
    # model_config = ConfigDict(
    #     arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
    #     populate_by_name=True,
    # )

    title: str = Field(description='titulo', alias='title')
    imagePath: str = Field(description='path image', alias='imagePath')
    url_project: str = Field(default='', description='path image', alias='url')

    class Config(BaseConfig):
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {
            ObjectId: lambda oid: str(oid)
        }


class User(BaseModel):
    #
    # model_config = ConfigDict(
    #     arbitrary_types_allowed=True,
    #     populate_by_name=True,
    # )

    # id_user: ObjectId = Field(description='user id', alias='_id')
    name: str
    login: str
    projects: List[Projects] = Field(alias='projects')

    class Config(BaseConfig):
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {
            ObjectId: lambda oid: str(oid)
        }


class CreateUserSchema(User):
    password: str
    passwordConfirm: str
    verified: bool = False


class LoginUserSchema(BaseModel):
    name: str
    password: str


class UserResponseSchema(User):
    id: str
    pass


class UserResponse(BaseModel):
    status: str
    user: UserResponseSchema
```